# Enterprise Architect & UML: subtleties when choosing interface or abstract class

Tags: interface, uml, abstract, enterprise-architect

I am currently building a model from existing C++ code. There is a (dynamically loadable) library that must therefore implement/provide a defined interface (class). The class which is used has some pure virtual functions, but it is - admittedly - not a pure interface (in the Java sense) as it is also a base class containing state (members) and a few method implementations.

So it is kind of a hybrid - base class in C++ *reality*, but an interface in its main *purpose*.

Note: I do not intent to generate some code, but the model should be correct for documentation purposes.

When drawing an example in EA (12), some questions arise:

[image]

a) are there any important reasons to prefer a class and make it 'abstract' (gray box "Base"), or should I directly use an Interface from the toolbox (purple box "Base2")? So far I could not notice any behavioral difference in EA except the color.

b) How can I suppress the stereotype {abstract} written behind the methods? When I do *not* set them to "abstract", they are not drawn in italic letters. But I want them italic, without the "{abstract}".

c) Similar question concerning the class/interface boxes: aren't interfaces abstract by definition? So why does EA add the {abstract} text here? It was sufficient to draw the class name italic.

d) I guess that the most left arrow (generalization of a base class) and the most right arrow (realization of an interface) are correct, and the middle one is not. Right?

Comment: Who are you documenting for? The *user* of the library or fellow *developers* of the library code? - Maybe you should create *two* diagrams.

Comment: The `abstract` is not a stereotype. I wonder how you produce that?

Comment: The documentation is mostly for regulatory reasons (stndard requires a documented software design for this kind of business), and, of course, for developers and myself as well, the motivation is say 80:20. For any human reader, every choice (abtract class/interface, with/without "{abstract}" is absulutely sufficient, I know. But since I have just begun EA for that task, I'd like to learn it right from the beginning. In EA, any action can cause impacts on another part of the model, this is not the case in a pure drawing tool like Visio.

Comment: Looks like you filled the multiplicity?

Comment: @Thomas: when pulling an Interface from the toolbox, it is already there. With classes, it appears when I set the class in Properties... / Details / Checkbox "Abstract". You are right, it is not a stereotype with << >>. But "abstract" is not provided in the default stereotype list for classes.

Comment: From which toolbox exactly do you pull?

Comment: The toolbox from the Class diagram. There are the icons "Interface" and "Class".

Comment: When I use that I get all that without `abstract`. Do you have any MDG turned on/add-in installed?

Comment: I am quite new with EA, so have no idea what MDG is... These three MDG technologies are active (Menu EXTENSIONS / MDG Technologies): "Basic UML 2 Technology", "Simple UML views", "Core Extensions". I think I'll write you a PM tonight...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Take either, but be consistent. The difference is a bit esoteric and except for rare cases not worth while (YMMV).

b) It looks like you filled Context/Advanced/Multiplicity with the value `abstract`

c) Yes. Interfaces are abstract and if you look at the Details tab you'll see that the `Abstract` box is ticked and can't be changed. I have no idea where that curly bracketed text comes from. It's not a stereotype. The only way I could show it like that was to change the type from `int` to `int {abstract}`.

d) You can well implement more than one interface in a class so theoretically all connectors are fine. So `Derived` implements two interfaces.

**Edit** As @minastros found out himself (and PMed me) the culprit was one of the zillion flags in the EA options:
[image]

Comment: b) no, I did not touch the Multiplicity. In the dialog where operations can be edited, there is a sub-window "Methods", where the attribute "Abstract" can be set to "True" (or "False", by default). As I said, if I leave it "False", the method will not be drawn italic. --- Thank you for the other answers!

Comment: UML allows metaproperties to be shown on a shape in braces, such as `{readonly}` and `{union}` . This can be toggled on or off in display options in MagicDraw. Perhaps you should be looking at display options in Sparx EA.

Comment: @JimL. the IsRoot e.g displays as `{root}` (along with the multiplicity, comma separated). `Abstract` is also one of those but for me it does not show in EA.

Comment: Maybe the OP should be asking Sparx.

Comment: @xmojmr The comments on the spec over there always make me grin... JimL.: Yes. Still cross posting on Sparx forum is always a good idea. In this case I would need some discussion. The OP seems to be new to EA and must be using something simple to create that appearance. I haven't seen that in more than 10 years using EA :-/

Comment: The UML 2.5 spec says, "The name of an abstract Classifier is shown in italics, where permitted by the font in use. Alternatively or in addition, an abstract Classifier may be shown using the textual annotation {abstract} after or below its name." Perhaps there is a separate control in Sparx EA for "textual annotations"?

Comment: None that I know of (but EA is a sack of easter eggs)

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas mentions, an interface *is* an abstract class technically, although an abstract class isn't always an interface.  If you have even one operation (method) that isn't implemented, the class is abstract, so it follows that if none of the operations are implemented, the class is also abstract.  An "abstract class" is often only thought of as a class with partial implementation since such an abstract class is different from an interface.  However, a class with no implementation--an interface--technically is also an abstract class.

That's probably why EA puts the {abstract} attribute on an interface (it isn't a stereotype in the diagram, it's an attribute--stereotypes use <>).  I wouldn't do it myself, since it goes without saying.

Comment: my main interest was whether EA makes another difference when I choose the 'interface' or the 'class' symbol except of the color, because basically, they seem to be redundant. Probably I would choose the 'interface' to express a higher abstraction, thus, to emphasise the interface _semantic_. Concerning the attribute - in hand written diagrams, "{abstract}" is more helpful than writing the title in italic, but in a PC diagram, I do not want both the italic name _and_ the attribute, especially with methods (I have already found that there is a setting in EA to disable it.).